# Is there a limitation in the size or the number of references added to the Visual Studio intellisense _reference.js file?

Tags: javascript, intellisense

We are using Google closure and have a process in place (using build events) that takes the `goog.require` and `goog.provide` statements (used to define dependencies between files) to create a dependency tree and then derive the content of the `_reference.js` file (basically the reference of all the files within the project). 
The final intention of this process is to have Intellisense for every class in the project in any file. The problem we are facing is that we are not getting Intellisense for all the files but only the first `N` in the list of reference. If we split the `_reference.js` file into several files it seems to fix the issue, so we are wondering if there is some limitation in the size of number of references that can be added into the `_reference.js` file, or maybe we are doing something intrinsically wrong with this approach. Any advice?

`Ctrl+J` did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly invoking IntelliSense (Ctrl + j usually) and see if that helps (explicitly invoking will give more time for IntelliSense to respond and build up contexts)

IntelliSense is generated by pseudo executing the JavaScript, so a large/complex file will take longer for it to process than the IntelliSense responsiveness will allow.

I'm not entirely sure why your approach is not working.  It should work by processing each file and then saving the results for the next invocation, picking up where it left off.

I'm thinking breaking the one large file into smaller files gives it more places to continue from where it left off.